# Incluir archivo .js en un Component Angular 4

Tags: angular4

Cómo se puede incluir un archivo .js dentro de un componente de Angular 4?

He buscado y en todos los ejemplos de cómo usar jQuery en un componente escriben directamente del código dentro de la exportación de la clase como [aquí](http://victorroblesweb.es/2016/12/26/como-usar-jquery-en-angular-2/):

```
export class AppComponent {
    // script
}
```

Qué métodos hay para "importar" o indicar la ruta de un script existente? Y cuál sería la mejor forma de organizar los scripts para poder reutilizarlo en todo el proyecto? O lo que, por convenio, se haga habitualmente en proyectos con Angular

Answer (score 1):

Añade la ruta de tus scripts en el fichero `.angular-cli.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": [
        "ruta/de/tu/script1.js",
        "ruta/de/tu/script2.js",
        "ruta/de/tu/script3.js"
    ]
}
```

Luego para su utilización lo más habitual es lo siguiente:

```
declare var $: any; // Para jQuery
```